# i have this error with tradingview code can anyone help me?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

> Blockquote

I'm trying but I can't fix it. It's an indicator on tradingview name: HAMI Pivot H/L Indicator , which I have convert to pine script v5.

but still getting this error

line 22: The function 'Sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.

can same one show me the right way to fix it ?

thank you in advance

> Blockquote

```
//@version=5

indicator('HAMI Pivot H/L ', overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)

//Basic
length = input.int(30, group='Basic Settings', tooltip='Pivot length. Use higher values for having lines connected to more significant pivots')
lookback = input.int(3, minval=1, group='Basic Settings', tooltip='Number of lines connecting a pivot high/low to display')
Slope = input.float(1., minval=-1, maxval=1, step=0.1, group='Basic Settings', tooltip='Allows to multiply the linear regression slope by a number within -1 and 1')

//Style
ph_col = input.color(#2157f3, 'Pivot High Lines Color', group='Line Colors')
pl_col = input.color(#ff1100, 'Pivot Low Lines Color', group='Line Colors')

//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Sma(src, p) =>
    a = ta.cum(src)
    (a - a[math.max(p, 0)]) / math.max(p, 0)
Variance(src, p) =>
    p == 1 ? 0 : Sma(src * src, p) - math.pow(Sma(src, p), 2)
Covariance(x, y, p) =>
    Sma(x * y, p) - Sma(x, p) * Sma(y, p)
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
n = bar_index
ph = ta.pivothigh(length, length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(length, length)
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
varip ph_array = array.new_float(0)
varip pl_array = array.new_float(0)
varip ph_n_array = array.new_int(0)
varip pl_n_array = array.new_int(0)
if ph
    array.insert(ph_array, 0, ph)
    array.insert(ph_n_array, 0, n)
if pl
    array.insert(pl_array, 0, pl)
    array.insert(pl_n_array, 0, n)
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
val_ph = ta.valuewhen(ph, n - length, lookback - 1)
val_pl = ta.valuewhen(pl, n - length, lookback - 1)
val = math.min(val_ph, val_pl)
k = n - val > 0 ? n - val : 2
slope = Covariance(close, n, k) / Variance(n, k) * Slope
var line ph_l = na
var line pl_l = na
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to lookback - 1 by 1
        ph_y2 = array.get(ph_array, i)
        ph_x1 = array.get(ph_n_array, i) - length
        pl_y2 = array.get(pl_array, i)
        pl_x1 = array.get(pl_n_array, i) - length
        ph_l := line.new(ph_x1, ph_y2, ph_x1 + 1, ph_y2 + slope, extend=extend.right, color=ph_col)
        pl_l := line.new(pl_x1, pl_y2, pl_x1 + 1, pl_y2 + slope, extend=extend.right, color=pl_col)
        pl_l
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the line to below
It will then calculate on each step

(p == 1 ? 0 : 1)*Sma(src * src, p) - math.pow(Sma(src, p), 2)